# Terrestrial Vertebrate Limbs

Tags: anatomy

This question is regarding the conversation that took place here: [Why don't mammals have more than 4 limbs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21772/9018). I'm not sure if someone mentioned this and I just missed it, but everyone is talking about two pairs of limbs for all terrestrial vertebrates; what about the case of kangaroos? If we are analyzing this from a locomotion point of view, and tails are being considered limbs, then wouldn't the kangaroo be considered to have five? They use their tail for balance and to push forward in "walking" (not exactly a walk, but I am lacking the proper term at the moment), resting only on the tail and forelimbs as the hind limbs swing forward. Does anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: This has recieved a fair amount of attention recently, as it made it into the lay press, [Unique Among Animals, Kangaroos Use Tail as Fifth Leg, Scientists Find](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2014/07/140701-kangaroo-animals-hopping-mammals-australia/)

Comment: I did not realize that was out there. Thank you for sharing that article!