# Why are there few four legged bugs?

Tags: entomology

I may be biased, and will delete if I'm wrong, but why are there so many more insects when compared to quad bugs?

Comment: What is the question exactly? Afaik, there are no invertebrates with 2 pairs of legs only. Is the question why, while we see that 2 pairs of legs is a successful bodyplan in vertebrates?

Comment: By "bugs" you mean insects, right? All insects have six legs (some may be reduced). Arachnids have eight legs. You can see [this](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/39210/3340) answer for some explanation on why six legs may be favourable to many insects. In general, it is not easy to reason out "why" something happened. Many times evolutionary choices are just random.

Comment: @Joce I wanted to know why six legged invertebrates are more successful than their four legged counterparts

Comment: @WYSIWYG Insects have six legs, and I want to know why is four not evolutionarily better for them

Comment: I don't see how this is a dupe