# Why do women mature (physically) earlier than men?

Tags: neuroscience, endocrinology, sex, human-evolution

All sources [I've read](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheRedPill/comments/2ce5o1/women_may_mature_earlier_but_men_mature_faster/) (the first page) states that the fact that women mature (in the sense of physical maturing) earlier than man is caused by the earlier selective prunning in brain. Though, this is an explanation just for the mechanism, not for the cause.

So what is the real evolutionary reason women mature earlier (though, [probably](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheRedPill/comments/2ce5o1/women_may_mature_earlier_but_men_mature_faster/) slower) than men?

Comment: When asking for "evoluitonary reason", always be careful to not fall into the pit of the panselectionist view of evolution (as briefly explained in the second paragraph of [this answer](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/why-dont-mammals-have-more-than-4-limbs/21776#21776)). This is just a warning but your question is fine!

Comment: What do you mean by "no chance in the concurence"? Otherwise, good question regarding ultimate versus proximate causes.

Comment: A quick look at "All sources I've read" suggests that the "maturing" here is entirely psychological, and quite subjective.  (And on a personal note, I've done quite well for some decades now by refusing to either "grow up" or "act my age" :-))

Comment: I have found many claims that women are in average 3 years ahead of men, when it comes to maturity, but I haven't found any study done to support this claim. However, it may appear true, and it actually does seem like this in reality (my own observation of peoples behaviors, just in general), There are also men who mature before women, and some women who mature late. Point being, that it could very well be genetic, but it could also be a psychological variable that is affected by ones environment, life situations and indoctrination.

Comment: I would like to add to my previous comment, regarding life situations... What is it that separates girls from boys in relation to passing time, when not in school (or at work?)... Basically during their free time, while growing up. Some people are required to be an adult at an early age too, an example because of the loss of a parent/guardian, thus they have to inherit some of the tasks of their lost one, so that the other parent/guardian isn't overwhelmed.

Comment: When you say `all sources I've read`, have you really read all  9,920,000 results? You might want to be more specific about what you read.

Comment: What kind of maturing are you asking about? Reproductive (sexual) maturity - the ability to ovulate and carry a pregnancy? Social maturity - acting like a "grown-up", not constantly making jokes centered around the physical elimination of waste, ability to maintain a polite conversation, ability to handle responsibilities and make appropriate decisions? Emotional maturity - the ability to recognize, validate, and control one's emotions in a socially-responsible manner? Physical maturity - achieving one's final height, full development of secondary sex characteristics, full set of teeth, etc.?

Comment: How about religious maturity - the ability to fully participate in all rituals and practices of your chosen religion or belief system? My point is, the word "maturity" on its own is vague and misleading. Your question is unclear, and needs to be edited to reflect **exactly** what you are asking about. You might also want to research a bit more than just glancing at the first page of a single vague Google search.

Comment: *`My guess is that the reproductive age of women is shorter and therefore they invest into the earlier development, unlike men that would have no chance in the concurence of all the men up to 70.`* This sentence makes absolutely zero sense to me. Please rewrite it in a grammatically correct and informative fashion. We don't have any clue what you're talking about or what point you're trying to get across. If you are having a difficult time expressing yourself in English, get a more fluent colleague, friend, or associate to help you.

Comment: @Remi.b The first page

Comment: @MattDMo All kinds of "maturities" are tightly bind together, just as I wrote, the mental maturity (religious, personality) is connected with the blood level of the hormones which is the key thing for the reproductive maturity.

Comment: @Probably your final paragraph in italics is fundamentally flawed. You seem to think that mating (and reproducing) is a zero-sum game, which it absolutely is not. First, you completely overlook the possibility of multiple partners. Second, your hypothesis that women are somehow automatically attracted to older men is just wrong, if you take 2 seconds to think about it. You block "older men" into a single group, and there's certainly a significant difference between an 18-year-old woman and a 30-year-old man vs. that same woman and a 70-yo man. Also, some women like younger men - just ask them.

Comment: @Probably *`"men don't affect the reproductive fitness of the offspring as much [as women]"`* Do you have **any** evidence whatsoever to support that statement? *`"older men have better chances to succeed between the girls because they're better physically developed"`* When was the last time you actually **looked** at an 18-yo standing next to a 50-yo man? Which one is more fit and "physically developed"? How do you know that older people have fewer parasites? It would be just as likely for them to have *more*, because they've lived longer and accumulated more.

Comment: @Probably *`"men are in principle fertile till death"`* Umm, no. That's just plain wrong. How many 60- or 70-yo new fathers do you know? *`"there's no reason of spending resources on the physicall development (maturing) in the age when they have no chance of succeeding between the other men (i.e., before 15 years)"`* Again, what does this even mean? Of course someone who has not hit puberty doesn't have a chance of "succeeding" because they're not even playing the game! Afterwards, it's pretty much an equal playing field. Male and female adults exist in equal numbers, so all get a chance.

Comment: @Probably *`"All kinds of "maturities" are tightly bind together, just as I wrote, the mental maturity (religious, personality) is connected with the blood level of the hormones which is the key thing for the reproductive maturity."`* No, I beg to differ. Sexual maturity has **nothing** to do with emotional or social maturity. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*, as the saying goes. There are plenty of teen parents who don't have as much social maturity as my 11-yo son.

Comment: @Probably Your *entire* question is a string of unsupported opinions tenuously connected together to give a completely unreasonable conclusion. You **still** haven't defined what you mean by "maturity", so it is impossible to know what you're asking about or to give a clear answer. Your "facts" are either misinterpreted or just wrong, and you clearly don't seem to understand evolution very well. I'd suggest taking the brief class [Understanding Evolution](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) from the University of California, Berkeley, then delving deeper into some topics.

Comment: @MattDMo: WRT 60-70 year old new fathers, you could probably find about as many as have the resources,  financial and otherwise, to attract women of childbearing age - and these days, of course, the desire to become fathers.  And for fitness, I know a number of 50+ individuals who are in far better shape than a lot of 18 year old couch potatos.  There's a lot more individual variation than you seem to think.

Comment: @jamesqf I was speaking (well, writing) there in generalities about populations, which is why I didn't bring up individual variation. Yes, of course there can be vast differences between individuals. Perhaps I should have said "average 18-yo vs. an average 50-yo". Women individually also have vastly different preferences for men. My overall point is that the OP has not thought through the question very carefully, and has made a lot of unsubstantiated claims, a number of which are simply incorrect.

Comment: @MattDMo Ok, thank you for your corrections. Just one basic thing: You don't a selective pressure to apply universally on the whole population, all you need it is just to be more stronger on individuals with some common trait. Apart from that I didn't mean "older men" as "elderly", I meant "more developed, mature" men.

Comment: As I said, of course men aren't fertile literally till death, the important thing is that the age is much longer than women's. Of course not everyone who is physically mature is as well sexually (I assume you mean maturity that consists of the awareness of your sexual identity, otherwise it's physical maturity) and mentally mature. I don't want to offend anyon but clearly, these things usually go along.

Comment: I've read it and there's nothing new for me. Please select the individual mistakes if you want to discuss them. I just find it obvious that there's much bigger difference between older women and young women than between young and older men.

Comment: @MattDMo: I agree on the lack of thinking through.  As I said earlier, most of the "maturity" seems to be purely subjective.  As for fathers in their 60s, my neighbor - 102 last birthday - has a daughter in her 40s, so it can be done.

Comment: @jamesqf I totally agree. Some family friends had an "oops" pregnancy when he was in his late 50s (she's probably 10-15 years younger than him), so it's definitely possible. All I'm saying is that it's rather rare.

Comment: @MattDMo: Sure, but I think the rarity is due less to physical inability, than to relatively few older men having the financial resources to attract women of childbearing age.

Comment: @MattDMo Ok, I've removed the part what I think, please don't consider it in your potential answer

Comment: I'm fine to delete any unfair comments from the list. The question can have two interpretations, it is a bit ambiguous: Why is there a gender difference in the age of maturation, growth and fertility in humans? One interpretation is biochemical reasons, and the other is human ecology and evolutionary reasons. The biochemical ones are subject to evolutionary pressure, as all neoteny is, so i understood the evolutionary pressures as being the driving factor for the reason of the difference. It's a very good quesiton that requires proper phrasing.

Comment: The problem with the question is that you refer to an article that talks about mental maturity, and you are instead querying about the entire process of different gender maturation time in males and females. what are the reasons for the earlier growth, physical and mental maturation of human males and females, and illustrate the query with a good summary of the ages males and females get different morphological and mental changes.

Comment: The tags you use are not related to the question.

Comment: @comprehensible Well all the sources were connecting the fact with the intensity of the selective prunning so I don't know why should it be so crutial to seperate mental and physical maturity but I'm asking primarily about the physical because I understand that such effects can be partially a work of society habits.

Answer (score -1):

This is a question about [Neoteny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoteny) and [Heterochrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterochrony).

The closest field of study which will have specialists of this kind of topic is the study of the late maturation of humans compared to other species, which has had some research: 5-7 years ago there were some papers measuring the different bone growth rates of humans compared to chimpanzees and exploring the notion of natural selection through preference of immature traits: being attracted to girls with child like faces, smaller nose, large eyes, small voice, babyish, with various causes for example allowing for later brain pruning and longer brain development.

If you research in google publications you can find [some research on the topic](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=neoteny%20humans%20sex&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5), for example:

Heterochrony in human evolution: the case for neoteny reconsidered

[Sexual selection, physical attractiveness, and facial neoteny: cross-cultural evidence and implications (1995)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2744016)

[The origins of sex differences in human behavior: Evolved dispositions versus social roles.](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/amp/54/6/408/)

It's all about evolutionary selection due to survival fitness. A complex age dynamic is at work in human evolution due to our extended lifetime, memory and brain size, amidst heavily variable social patterns (mate selection, monogamy, tribe size, bride rights, patriarchal/matriarchal systems) in paleolithic humans.

Bonobos mature at roughly the same time: 9 years, and female bonobos have a baby at 11 to 13 years. I think that illustrates the flexibility of maturation age according to the role of the adults.

Human females can have babies in between 9 and 15 years for the most part, some of them at 7, so maturation age is an evolutionary trait rapidly changeable according to fitness of the resulting offspring, so it is entirely fine tuned by survival performance.

EDIT: I wrote this answer to be helpful, but apparently my lack of sources and "errors?" deserve a mark down. so here is an additional [text](http://They%20found%20that%20Paleolithic%20girls%20arrived%20at%20menarche%20-%20the%20first%20occurrence%20of%20menstruation%20-%20between%20seven%20and%2013%20years.%20This%20is%20a%20similar%20age%20to%20modern%20girls,%20which%20suggests%20that%20this%20is%20the%20evolutionarily%20determined%20age%20of%20puberty%20in%20girls.%20%20'This%20would%20have%20matched%20the%20degree%20of%20psychosocial%20maturation%20necessary%20to%20function%20as%20an%20adult%20in%20Paleolithic%20society%20based%20on%20small%20groups%20of%20hunter-gatherers,'%20they%20write.%20%20Disease%20and%20poor%20nutrition%20became%20more%20common%20as%20humans%20settled,%20causing%20puberty%20to%20be%20delayed.%20Modern%20hygiene,%20nutrition%20and%20medicine%20have%20allowed%20the%20age%20of%20menarche%20to%20fall%20to%20its%20original%20range.%20%20However,%20today%20there%20is%20a%20mismatch%20between%20sexual%20maturity%20and%20psychosocial%20maturity,%20with%20sexual%20maturity%20occurring%20much%20earlier.%20This%20mismatch%20is%20a%20result%20of%20society%20becoming%20vastly%20more%20complex,%20with%20psychosocial%20maturity%20therefore%20taking%20longer%20to%20reach.):

"They found that Paleolithic girls arrived at menarche - the first occurrence of menstruation - between seven and 13 years. This is a similar age to modern girls, which suggests that this is the evolutionarily determined age of puberty in girls.

'This would have matched the degree of psychosocial maturation necessary to function as an adult in Paleolithic society based on small groups of hunter-gatherers,' they write.

Disease and poor nutrition became more common as humans settled, causing puberty to be delayed. Modern hygiene, nutrition and medicine have allowed the age of menarche to fall to its original range.

However, today there is a mismatch between sexual maturity and psychosocial maturity, with sexual maturity occurring much earlier. This mismatch is a result of society becoming vastly more complex, with psychosocial maturity therefore taking longer to reach."

Note that they are talking about female adult paleolithic maturity and tasks at that age. Females compete for mates by attractiveness and fitness, and some research suggests that males compete for females by other mechanisms, even force or threat.([ref](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Puts/publication/280979632_Human_Sexual_Selection/links/55cfa23c08ae118c85c00baa.pdf))

There is clearly a reason for which men are available to make and care for their offspring later than females. Females prefer older males by at least a couple of years with moderate adult muscle mass[(ref)](http://psp.sagepub.com/content/33/8/1167), and in our species males of 17 to 35 years are biologically the strongest and [wisest](http://www.sciencealert.com/this-is-the-age-you-reach-peak-intelligence-according-to-science). Nature would have it that 11 /13 year old fathers clearly are [counter productive](http://digitalcommons.liberty.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1008&context=ccfs_fac_pubs) to the survival of their partner and child in an ordinary setting of hunter gatherers, because of the very long gestation and complexity of human survival tasks.

The human mental maturation range has a wide variety of [deviation](http://mentalhealthdaily.com/2015/02/18/at-what-age-is-the-brain-fully-developed/), and between the age of 8 and 25, we are pre-programmed to be in an intense task of [learning](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3049106/) and physical adventure. Physical coordination of the male can reach an optimal level as late as the age of 22, 3/4 years after his bones have finished growing and his muscles and reflexes have had time to increase and adapt to his new frame, which is why athletes are at their physical peak between the ages of 18-27, and the "mental pruning" article suggests that their mind continues to re-organize itself well beyond the age of 30. During that stage, a human male is programmed to [learn](http://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199551224.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199551224-e-002) a wide array of advanced skills: flint knapping, tool making, botanic knowledge, hunting skills, clothes making, landscape exploration, orientation, memorization of food places, wells, tree climbing, metal work, net weaving, pottery, pigments, weapons, blow darts, wild animal experience (game, lions, rhinos, birds, rodents, traps, stalking, poisons, frogs) etc... All that time based survival experience reinforces the notion that a male reaches his functional optimum as a provider and protector of his family well after his sexual maturation age.

Females have a less physically intensive [role to play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_roles_among_the_indigenous_peoples_of_North_America) in human society. While they can learn all the hunting/survival skills of the male, their central [role](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjo46KaltrQAhUQsBQKHdB2BFcQFghNMAc&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FGender_roles_among_the_indigenous_peoples_of_North_America&usg=AFQjCNHSeyvU7P30c-YNysmYww5YwNtM6g&sig2=9aVxK7u5vTLtGgCb-8-sXQ) is to be nourished and provide for the child([ref](http://anthro.vancouver.wsu.edu/media/Course_files/anth-302-barry-hewlett/melkonner.pdf)). Their parenting tasks rely less on individual memory because they stay socially at home more (papua new gineans, africans, aborigines, yanomami). Their task can be less intense physically, require less physical training, and can be less [intensive on memory](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/the-characteristics-of-hunter-gatherer-fitness/) and adventure (being nourished, childcare, craftwork, leadership of the group at home and less in exploration and precarious tasks). Both the human male and female memory has a very important role for guiding the group. A female can provide guidance up till the age of 50-90 in a natural setting.

Females are generally less expendable and adventurous than males, because a male can potentially have 3 offspring every day, he is limited by the number of females, and she can only have 1 offspring every 9 months, she is more precious to the multiplication of the group.

Add to that the function of memory, hunter gatherer fitness, and social acumen, absorption of mental and survival skills

Other great apes have gestation periods arount 8.5 months compared to our 9.

Because of the difficulty to assess the paleolithic social and environmental pressures that caused the sex age maturation difference, it's a question that theorists would be unwise to wade into to any great depth, in an academically competetive field. A good anthropologist should be able to list all the predominant selection factors.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and is really just a bunch of hand-waving without much in the way of supporting citations. *`"It is well-known that females prefer older males with young adult muscle mass in almost all species"`* Actually, it isn't. Citation needed. *`"maturation age is an evolutionary trait entirely tuneable according to fitness of the resulting offspring, so it is entirely fine tuned by survival performance."`* Again, citation needed. Finally, your last sentence basically says *"I read the first results from a Google search and don't actually know what I'm talking about."*

Comment: Onset of menarche at 9 years old is a *very* recent phenomenon due to significantly increased environmental exposure to estrogen and its analogs, as well as some other as-yet-unagreed-upon causes. [Historically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menarche#Changes_in_time_of_average_age), girls living in 6th to 15th century Europe, for example, began menstruating at an average age of 14.

Comment: Finally, your last sentence basically says "I read the first results from a Google search and don't actually know what I'm talking about" ... No it sais your markdown is idiotic. I search science publications for 30 minutes and find that the topic, which is conjectural, has virtually no precedent, I publish here what precedent there is in related fields. I'm not inclined to argue with someone who speaks nonsense and who has no better answer than I do. You are an example of a negative forum contributor with low experience in biological academia. Use established measurements from extant tribes.

Comment: They found that Paleolithic girls arrived at menarche - the first occurrence of menstruation - between seven and 13 years. This is a similar age to modern girls, which suggests that this is the evolutionarily determined age of puberty in girls. That's not just one factual accuracy of my text. you may as well consider the entire text as relatively well informed... and learn... because you are not informed, and yet you act as if you were. listen and learn. i'm certainly not a very good biologist in this field but i am effortlessly less misguided than yourself.

Comment: Much of the information contained in this post requires additional references. Please [edit] to add citations to reliable sources that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or deleted. I don't care if your statements are correct or not, they still need to be supported by peer-reviewed literature. Scientists understand that. I'm not going to address your personal attacks, as they only reflect negatively on yourself. You don't know me, so don't make assumptions.

Comment: I never mark down other users except if they provide negative imput to the forum, because i have regard and empathy for their efforts. your first comment contains a flat personal critique, and your second comment contains a falsehood. clearly you are not wise enough to interact with the page, citing false information as you do. I've added references for everything, because i didn't stray into inexperience as you did in you second comment, oxford and cambridge zoology. botany, human sciences, and ecology departments dont provide a narrow base of culture: read a single book on human sciences.