# Are the 5 digits of all land vertebrates an accidental number?

Tags: evolution, vertebrates

All land verterbrates except some frogs have 5 fingers on hands and feet.

The first vertebrate lizards came out of the water and had 7 fingers ( -370mn yrs), and then 6 fingers, and after 30 million years, all their descendents had 5 fingers on both limbs.

someone told me "5 is much more of an accidental number", so if all land vertebrates had 7, then 6 fingers, why did that get selected to 5?

Comment: Related (if not duplicate): [Why don't mammals have more than 4 limbs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/why-dont-mammals-have-more-than-4-limbs) and [Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/35532/why-do-some-bad-traits-evolve-and-good-ones-dont)

Comment: There are more exceptions than frogs. It depends a bit upon what you call a finger, but typically snakes don't have fingers, ungulates don't have fingers, cats have 4 toes at each hind paw, ....

Comment: Note also that the first vertebrate coming out of the water was not a [lizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lizard) (not a *squamata*).

Comment: By the question `why did that get selected to 5` there is a potential false assumption that make it clear that your question is a duplicate of `Why do some bad traits evolve, and good ones don't?`. I'm voting to close as duplicate. Please have a look at this post and if you think it did not answer your answer, please clearly explain why.

Comment: The general question is a duplicate. Articles [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/why-do-most-species-have/), [here](http://phenomena.nationalgeographic.com/2014/08/01/how-did-you-get-five-fingers/), and [here](http://www.sbs.com.au/topics/science/humans/article/2016/08/01/ask-evolution-why-do-we-have-five-fingers) emphasize the contingent nature of the five-finger tetrapod.