# Live birth versus eggs

Tags: zoology

Would it be right to say that animals or birds that have ears visible outside, including say holes in the head, give birth, and those that have ears concealed inside the head, lay eggs? The point is not to go to minute biological terminology, and if we can resist that urge of vengeance, would the above be an OK statement?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I am afraid the terminology might matter more than you'd hope. Maybe you could give specific examples that pushed you to think that such correlation would exist. I don't know much about hearing (and I am not a very good naturalist) but when I think of lizards and birds, I think of many species that 1) lay eggs and 2) have holes in the head for hearing.

Comment: You might want to read a little bit about phylogenetic signal to avoid the misinterpretation of such correlation as being the result of selection. You might typically want to have a look at the post [Why don't mammals have more than 4 limbs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21772/why-dont-mammals-have-more-than-4-limbs/21776#21776).

Comment: Thank you  nothing pushed me  simply, please tell me  three species that have holes in the head for hearing which are visible from outside, and also lay eggs?

Comment: You said "holes in the head", not "visible from the outside" in your question. By saying "visible from the outside", I don't really know how visible they need to be but these details probably won't matter much. Consider any owls ([pics](https://www.google.ca/search?q=owl+ears&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjitofX67fYAhVF0GMKHbBLAJkQsAQIKA&biw=1245&bih=680)) or many lizards such as for example [this alligator lizard](https://www.google.ca/search?q=common+wall+lizard+ear&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjV1d7367fYAhUW8WMKHfFkAkEQ_AUICigB&biw=1245&bih=680#imgrc=LoEjXqqga_zNgM:).

Comment: you might want to accept LinuxBlanker answer just so that the question is marked as answer.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

Animals without noticeable outer ear that give birth: cetaceans (dolphins, whales and such), lots of pinnipeds (sea lions, seals and such).

Animals with noticeable outer ear that lay eggs (as suggested in @Remi.b's comment): owls, lizards.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

[Vivipary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viviparity) and [ovovivipary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ovoviviparity) have evolved multiple times in multiple lineages, laying eggs is the ancestral/basal condition for tetrapods but it has been lost multiple times.